# extra space between pagination and footer on wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Here's my site in development: http://www.modernfuture.net/wordpress

I've been searching post after post to find a solution and I've come up empty handed. For some reason there's extra space between the bottom of the pagination and the footer. I've tried setting a max-height and/or height value on all the divs & that didn't work. I've tried adding a div wrapper around the body but that only messes up the rest of the site.

I really need some help on this and I would greatly appreciate an original response & not a link to someone else's post. I know this is a topic that's been brought up before, but I've been reading other people's posts on this matter and it's been more of a headache than helpful. Please be kind as I'm relatively new to Wordpress.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `bottom:210px;` defined for `.wrapper section[role="main"]`. Remove that style. It will work fine.

It is in line 92 of the stylesheet: http://modernfuture.net/wordpress/wp-content/themes/html5blank-master/style.css?ver=1.0

Also define a **height** for **.header**.

Comment: How'd you come to this solution?? Just curious...Thanks!!

Comment: I inspected using firebug in Mozilla from outer div's.

Answer (score 0):

## conditionizr  this division seems to be the problem.  You may want to rewrite the height, the margins and padding.  Some values may seem to come from a script.